# Vectorize a regression map calculation

Tags: matlab, performance, regression, vectorization, covariance

I compute the regression map of a time series `A(t)` on a field `B(x,y,t)` in the following way:

```
A=1:10; %time
B=rand(100,100,10); %x,y,time

rc=nan(size(B,1),size(B,2));
for ii=size(B,1)
  for jj=1:size(B,2)
     tmp = cov(A,squeeze(B(ii,jj,:))); %covariance matrix
     rc(ii,jj) = tmp(1,2); %covariance A and B
  end
end
rc = rc/var(A); %regression coefficient
```

Is there a way to vectorize/speed up code? Or maybe some built-in function that I did not know of to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to vectorize this algorithm, you would have to "get your hands dirty" and compute the covariance yourself. If you take a look inside `cov` you'll see that it has many lines of input checking and very few lines of actual computation, to summarize the critical steps:

```
y = varargin{1};
x = x(:);
y = y(:);
x = [x y];
[m,~] = size(x);
denom = m - 1;
xc = x - sum(x,1)./m;  % Remove mean
c = (xc' * xc) ./ denom;
```

To simplify the above somewhat:

```
x = [x(:) y(:)];
m = size(x,1);
xc = x - sum(x,1)./m;
c = (xc' * xc) ./ (m - 1);
```

Now this is something that is fairly straightforward to vectorize...

```
function q51466884
A = 1:10; %time
B = rand(200,200,10); %x,y,time
%% Test Equivalence:
assert( norm(sol1-sol2) < 1E-10);
%% Benchmark:
disp([timeit(@sol1), timeit(@sol2)]);

%%
function rc = sol1()
rc=nan(size(B,1),size(B,2));
for ii=1:size(B,1)
  for jj=1:size(B,2)
     tmp = cov(A,squeeze(B(ii,jj,:))); %covariance matrix
     rc(ii,jj) = tmp(1,2); %covariance A and B
  end
end
rc = rc/var(A); %regression coefficient
end

function rC = sol2()  
m = numel(A);
rB = reshape(B,[],10).'; % reshape
% Center:
cA = A(:) - sum(A)./m;
cB = rB - sum(rB,1)./m;
% Multiply:
rC = reshape( (cA.' * cB) ./ (m-1), size(B(:,:,1)) ) ./ var(A);
end

end
```

I get these timings: `[0.5381 0.0025]` which means we saved two orders of magnitude in the runtime :)

Note that a big part of optimizing the algorithm is assuming you don't have any "strangeness" in your data, like `NaN` values etc. Take a look inside `cov.m` to see all the checks that we skipped.